# Add joomla SEF Translate Module or component to php,html web site

Tags: php, html, joomla-component, joomla-module, language-translation

I want to add Joomla SEF Translate Module or Component to my php,html Website Page. how can i include this module and how to run this. please tell anyone

Thanks advance

Comment: still any one does not reply for this why ? any wrong reason is here please tell me ?

Comment: I posted an answer.  Can you comment on the answer and let me know if it is working or not?  I would like to help you...

Answer (score 0):

To install a component in Joomla, go to the Administration Interface (back-end) and open Extension Manager(Under the Extensions menu).  In the Extension Manager the default page should be the Installation Manager.  Install the component using the upload, install from directory, or install from URL methods.

If it installs correctly you should see the SEF component now listed under the Components menu.  Configure it as needed (instructions can be found on the component provider's website.

Then open Module Manager (under the Extensions menu) and create a new Module (if it not already there).  Choose SEF from the list, create a Title, fill in all the public information etc, and specify the correct values under the tab Menu Assignment.  Save it and close it.

Your SEF module should now be visible on your website (and on the pages that you specified under Menu Assignment).

To customize the SEF module, refer to the SEF Translate website.